# Can an api return a function?

Tags: javascript, microservices

What would be the shortfalls of fetching constructor functions via api?

Basically, if you have a calculation, which, based on locale shows a different calculation. I would like to have a microservice return the actual constructor function for the tax calculator , so calling  var Tax = callService("tax","locale1") would return the tax function, pre-configured to the specific locale.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What kind of API are we talking about? In languages where functions are first class citizens, this is obviously true. If we're talking about network protocol APIs, the answer is generally no.. such as in HTTP. However, you can do something with this using RPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is an API that "returns a function" I suppose that you will have "something" to interpret the answer. So If I suppose you working on web and you have a front whose interpret is the browser. You can use JS Reflect to call methods based on an answer. For example calling the function by name and with specific params that you can define also in the answer.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect

Answer is based on what I understand of you question. Sorry If Im going to different aproach.

Comment: Yes, thanks... this is close to what I am looking for..  I will read up and try to make the question clearer...

Answer (score 1):

You probably want an RPC library that lets you interact with a remote server as if it was local.

You can take a look at something like https://www.zerorpc.io/ to do this. The concept is simple: you create remote endpoint services that "feel like" local objects but are really doing remote invocations.

If you mean something else -- such as a local API, your question needs clarifcation.